# INSERTING VALUES INTO A NESTED TABLE

Tags: sql, oracle, nested-table

I am trying to develop a university database with the help of nested tables, I have successfully created all other nested tables required and inserted data as well, but while inserting data into marks table I am facing problem of inconsistent datatype.

codes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MODULE_MARKS;
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MM_NT_TYPE AS TABLE OF REF MODULE_MARKS;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MODULE_MARKS AS OBJECT
(
  MODULE REF MODULE_T, MARKS_OBTAINED, TOTAL_MARKS, STATUS
)

CREATE TABLE MARK_TAB
(
  student ref student_t,
  modules_marks mm_nt_type
)
```

I am able to insert reference to student correctly but I want to insert data into module_marks.

Tried doing :

```
INSERT INTO MARK_TAB VALUES((SELECT REF(S) FROM STUDENT_TAB S WHERE 
S.S_ID=1), 
MM_NT_TYPE( MODULE_MARKS_T((SELECT REF (M) FROM MODULE_TAB M WHERE 
M.MODULE_ID =1),
90,100,'PASS')));
```

this shoes the error ORA-00932. EXPECTED REFERENCE OF MODULE_MARKS_T GOT MODULE_MARKS_T.

Comment: What is the data type of student and  modules_marks. You have opted the data type from another object, but what is the actual data type. Check the data type you are using to insert and existing data type

Answer (score 0):

It seems a familiar structure to me. Maybe I have created the same structure for one of my projects.

I think you are confused when inserting the record in the column having a type which is table of REF.

I have `COURSES_TABLE_TYPE` which is table of `REF COURSES_T` and courses table is table of `COURSES_T`;

I suggest you do the following:

```
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT VALUES (
    1,
    COURSES_TABLE_TYPE((  -- REFs of single records delimited by comma
        SELECT
            REF(C)
        FROM
            COURSE C
        WHERE
            COURSE_ID = 1
    ),(
        SELECT
            REF(C)
        FROM
            COURSE C
        WHERE
            COURSE_ID = 2
    ))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`MM_NT_TYPE` is a collection of `REF MODULE_MARKS` whereas you are passing `MODULE_MARKS` objects and not references. Instead, you need to have a table containing containing `MODULE_MARKS` objects that you can reference:

```sql
CREATE TABLE module_marks_tab OF module_marks;
```

Then you can reference those objects. For example:

```sql
INSERT INTO mark_tab VALUES (
  ( SELECT REF(s) FROM students s WHERE id = 2 ),
  MM_NT_TYPE(
    ( SELECT REF( m ) FROM module_marks_tab m WHERE m.module.id = 1 AND marks_obtained = 3 ),
    ( SELECT REF( m ) FROM module_marks_tab m WHERE m.module.id = 3 AND marks_obtained = 8 )
  )
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8f103d98077b68b004c2744c61e0ebc4)